# Blackberry vertical scrolling for side by side vertical managers

Tags: blackberry

I have to built this UI for Blackberry JRE 4.6 & above.
Please suggest the approach for this UI.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the right place to come with requests like "can somebody do my work for me?"  You will get better response if you show what work you have done already and ask specific questions about the place(s) where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, here is the approach,

1. Take horizontal manager for header

   HorizontalFieldManager nonscrollableHFM= new HorizontalFieldManager();
2. Take another horizontal manager as a container

   HorizontalFieldManager containerHfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

   2.1 Add vertical manager for left section (Non Scrollable)

   VerticalFieldManager leftVfm = new VerticalFieldManager();

   2.2 Create a custom vertical manager for right section as below

{

```
   class RightVfm extends VerticalFieldManager {

  RightVfm() {

    super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL
    | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR | USE_ALL_WIDTH);

      }

  protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

      super.sublayout(width, getPreferredHeight());

      setExtent(width, getPreferredHeight());

  }

  public int getPreferredWidth() {

     return _width;

  }

public void setWidth(int w) {

            _width = w;

        }

public int getPreferredHeight() {

            return _height;

        }

public void setHeight(int h) {

            _height = h;

        }

    private int _width;
    private int _height;

};
```

}

1. Adjust the height & width of right verticle manager by calling setHeight & setWidth   methods

   I got help from here,
   http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/209190-set-height-verticalfieldmanager.html